# How to use "tr" to replace a digit in a number

Tags: bash, replace, digits, tr

My input file contains some series of commands for a number for eg.

```
13287
13288
13289
```

I want the following output in all the file.

```
13281
13282
13283
```

I am using the following command saved in a script file as I pass the first four digits as argument in the script file.

```
#!/bin/bash
cat $1_final.txt | tr "$17" "$11" > $1.tmp
```

Instead of the desired output I am getting the following output. I have checked again the argument passed it 1328 else it will not be able to get the file because the file in the directory is 1328_final.txt

```
13221
```

Where I am doing this wrong?

Comment: So basically you want to subtract 6 from each line?

Comment: no, Sorry for any confusions.. the file has these numbers all over the place.There are not consecutively placed as shown here.

Answer (score 1):

the first argument to `tr` is a *set* of characters which will be globally replaced by the corresponding letter from the 2nd arg, another *set* of characters.

To subtract 6 from each line can be accomplished in many ways:

```
while read num; do echo $((num-6)); done < file
awk '{print $1 - 6}' file
sed 's/$/ - 6/' file | bc
sed 's/$/ 6 - p/' file | dc
```